# Conditional cron job using SLURM scheduler

Tags: cron, slurm

I'm currently running jobs on a computing cluster that uses the slurm workload manager. I can view all of the jobs I currently have running with:

```sh
$ squeue -u <username>
             JOBID PARTITION  NAME       USER ST     TIME  NODES NODELIST(REASON)
           3379570   sixhour job01 <username> PD     0:00      1 (Priority)
           3409269   sixhour job02 <username>  R 03:06:13      1 n387
```

So in this example, I have two jobs that have been submitted. `job01` is pending, and `job02` has been running for around 3 hours.

I want to set up a cron job that will only submit the job if it's not listed in the above view. Take the following cron file as an example:

```
MAILTO=""
* */1 * * * sbatch job01.sh
* */1 * * * sbatch job02.sh
* */1 * * * sbatch job03.sh
```

Using this cron file, each job would get submitted every hour. But because `job01` and `job02` are already listed under `squeue -u <username>`, I only want `job03` to actually get submitted.

Is there a way I can add some conditional logic to the cron file?

Comment: Instead of calling `sbatch` directly from `cron`, create a script that performs the needed checks before launching the job and put it in place of the `sbatch`.

Comment: What's the purpose here? To have a job automatically re-submitted?

Comment: @damienfrancois My use case is actually the inverse. I have a tweet-bot set up to run at set intervals. Sometimes, depending on the workload of the computing cluster, I get 5-6 jobs stacked up in the queue that all end up running at the same time once space frees up. This would prevent additional tweet-bot jobs from stacking up in the queue if there is already one there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

jobnames=$(squeue -h --user <username> --format %j)

for jobname in job{01..03} ; do
grep "$jobname" <<< "$jobnames" >/dev/null || sbatch "$jobname.sh"
done
```

This script will collect all job names related to jobs submitted by `<username>` in `$jobnames` and then iterate over the ones it should expect. If one is not found, `grep` will return non-zero exit code and the `|| sbatch` will be executed.

Replace the three lines in your cron file with a single one running the above script.

Comment: You can alternatively replace the grep line with ``[[ $jobnames == *$jobname* ]] || sbatch "$jobname.sh"``